# Confused by db_option in CnosDB

Tags: cnosdb

I read the database creation section of the official documentation of CnosDB, it shows:

```
db_options:
    db_option ...

db_option: {
      TTL value
    | SHARD value
    | VNODE_DURATION value
    | REPLICA value
    | PRECISION {'ms' | 'us' | 'ns'}
}
...
SHARD: represents the number of data partitions, defaults to 1.
VNODE_DURATION: represents the time range of data in the shard, defaults to 365 days, and also expressed by data with units.Its data meaning is consistent with the value of TTL.
...
```

The relationship between these two options seems confusing, and I can't understand the sharding rules.

Comment: Like you have the internet just search for it dude.